# Rails 3 refactoring ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, refactoring

I have the following query which looks up an organisation belonging to the current signed in user and then finds any events belonging to that organisation.

```
def update
    @organisation = current_user.organisations.find(params[:organisation_id])
    @event = @organisation.events.find(params[:id])
    if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
        # Handle a successful update.
        flash[:success] = "Event updated"
        redirect_to organisation_event_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

This currently results in 2 queries to the database, which whilst not necessarily a problem, I feel should be able to be achieved in one query. Is that possible or does it need to be 2? If the former, how should I go about achieving it?

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
current_user.organisations.joins(:events).where(["id = ? AND events.id = ?", params[:organisation_id], params[:id]]).first()
```

Answer (score 1):

The query could be refactored in this way:

```
def update
    @event = Event.joins(:organisations).where("id = ? AND organisation_id = ? AND user_id = ?", params[:id], params[:organisation_id], current_user.id).first()
    if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
        # Handle a successful update.
        flash[:success] = "Event updated"
        redirect_to organisation_event_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```